# Enabling mod_rewrite on Amazon Linux

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to enable mod_rewrite on an Amazon Linux instance. My Directory directives look like this:

```
<Directory />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/vhosts">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options None
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

And then further down in httpd.conf I have the `LoadModule` directive:

```
... other modules...
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
... other modules...
```

I have commented out all the Apache modules not needed by Wordpress.

Still when I issue http restart and then check the loaded modules with `/usr/sbin/httpd -l` I get only:

```
[root@foobar]# /usr/sbin/httpd -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c
```

Inside the virtual host containing the Wordpress site I have an `.htaccess` containing:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The .htaccess is owned by apache which is the user apache runs under. The `apachectl -t` command returns `Syntax OK`

My `/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin foobar@gmail.com
     ServerName foobar.net
     ServerAlias www.foobar.net
     DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/foobar/
     ErrorLog /var/www/vhosts/foobar/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/vhosts/foobar/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What am I doing wrong? What should I check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My configuration was correct but I needed

```
Options FollowSymLink
```

in my DocumentRoot's declaration in httpd.conf for mod_rewrite to work.

Answer (score 6):

The LoadModule directive will load a module dynamically.

Try issuing `RewriteEngine on` in a virtual host followed by `apachectl -t` to confirm weather or not the module is actually loaded.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for the answer I've added more detail to the question regarding what you pointed out. RewriteEngine is on and apachectl -t returns Syntax OK but still doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my last comment it was wrong. You've taken this from the wordpress .htaccess file haven't you? Do you have AllowOverride all enabled in your VHost configuration?

Comment: Hi James, yes I've taken it from WP. Yes the AllowOverride on the subdirectories of my DocumentRoot is set to All

Comment: Please try this: In the server configuration - not .htaccess add the lines `RewriteEngine On` and `RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.wordpress.org/ [R]` to confirm if rewrite is functioning at all. It should pass all traffic to the Wordpress website.

Comment: I deleted the .htaccess from WP and did the changes you suggested but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I just started a fresh amazon linux and had the same issue and the `Options FollowSymLink` were there but the next line `AllowOverride None` had to be changed to `AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 4):

I got the solution for this problem.....

I have changed `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride all`, below 
`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` in the config file `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

Thanks!